# Connect to the right serial port in Unix

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, unix

## Background

I'm trying to connect to a device using `UART` though a micro-USB cable and `GNU screen` from *Ubuntu* and *OSX*.

On both Ubuntu and *OSX* I can get the most recent serial connection with the following command, which I have run just after having connected my device and turned it on.

```
ls -t /dev/tty* | head -n 1
```

On *Ubuntu* I get (this is actually the output of `ll` and `-n 3` so I can see better what's shown)

```
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166,  0 Jan 29 10:51 /dev/ttyACM0
crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty       5,  0 Jan 29 10:14 /dev/tty
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout   4, 68 Jan 21 16:19 /dev/ttyS4
```

and the first item is correct (i.e. I can `screen /dev/ttyACM0 115200`).

On *Mac*, instead, I get this

```
crw--w----  1 atcold  tty     16,   4 29 Jan 10:56 /dev/ttys004
crw-rw-rw-  1 root    wheel   19,  44 29 Jan 10:56 /dev/tty.usbmodemfd121
crw--w----  1 atcold  tty     16,   6 28 Jan 16:21 /dev/ttys006
```

and the first item is wrong (I cannot connect to it) whereas the working one is the second one (and I had to turn off and turn on my device twice, since the first time there was not any `/dev/tty.usbmodemfd121` at all).

## Question

My question is easy. How can I access automatically the *correct* serial connection? I'm trying to avoid to give too many troubles to the final user trying to sort this problem out automatically.

## Answer

This is my final script :)

```
read -p "Connect the switched off board, then press <Enter>" temp
ls /dev/tty* > /tmp/old_tty
read -p "Turn on the board and press <Enter>" temp
ls /dev/tty* > /tmp/new_tty
screen $(comm -13 /tmp/old_tty /tmp/new_tty) 115200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution could be to dectect the active serial connection before and after plugging the micro-usb, and then connect to the one present only after the micro-usb is plugged. This can be done for example with an sh script

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH_SUFFIX="/dev/tty"

read -p "Be sure the mini usb adapter is unplugged then press ENTER" temp
BEFORE=`ls -1 ${PATH_SUFFIX}* `
read -p "Now plug device and then press ENTER" temp
# sleep 2 seconds to be sure the filedevise is created
sleep 2
AFTER=`ls -1 ${PATH_SUFFIX}*`

OLD_IFS=$IFS

IFS='
'

for file in $AFTER ; do
    if case ${BEFORE} in *"${file}"*) false;; *) true;; esac; then
        FOUND=$file
    fi
done

IFS=$OLD_IFS

#Now do whatever with FOUND device
echo $FOUND
```

Comment: LOL, I cannot believe I had `/dev/ttys004` also before connecting my device (since its time stamp, I was sure it was generated by connecting my device)! Do you have any suggestion (`sh` code snippet) about detecting the new active serial connection?

Comment: @Atcold I added a sample sh script

Comment: A-W-E-S-O-M-E-!-!-!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at setting up a udev rule to create a symlink with a specific name for this serial device.

Assuming you can identify the device by vendor or serial number.

This should help:

http://noctis.de/ramblings/linux/49-howto-fixed-name-for-a-udev-device.html